# HtmlExtensions looking for this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, htmlextensions

i've attempted to add some htmlextensions to my mvc project. When i try to use them they are all expecting a this HtmlHelper htmlHelper parameter? but according to all examples these are not expected.. what i am doing wrong?

public static string RadioButtonListFor(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Expression> expression, String tagBase) where TModel : class
        {
            return htmlHelper.RadioButtonListFor(expression, tagBase, null);
        }

```
    public static string RadioButtonListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, RadioButtonListViewModel>> expression, String tagBase, object htmlAttributes) where TModel : class
    {
        return htmlHelper.RadioButtonListFor(expression, tagBase, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static string RadioButtonListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, RadioButtonListViewModel>> expression, String tagBase, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) where TModel : class
    {
        var inputName = tagBase;
        RadioButtonListViewModel radioButtonList = GetValue(htmlHelper, expression);

        if (radioButtonList == null)
            return String.Empty;

        if (radioButtonList.ListItems == null)
            return String.Empty;


        var containerTag = new TagBuilder("td");
        containerTag.MergeAttribute("id", inputName + "_Container");
        foreach (var item in radioButtonList.ListItems)
        {
            var radioButtonTag = RadioButton(htmlHelper, inputName, new SelectListItem { Text = item.Text, Selected = item.Selected, Value = item.Value.ToString() }, htmlAttributes);

            containerTag.InnerHtml += radioButtonTag;
        }

        return containerTag.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are writing extension methods for [HtmlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492619%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) class. When ever you want to use your extension method you have to import the namespace in which your extension method is in.

Say for example `RadioButtonListFor` is in `MyNamespace`

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static string RadioButtonListFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, RadioButtonListViewModel>> expression, String tagBase, object htmlAttributes) where TModel : class
        {
             return htmlHelper.RadioButtonListFor(expression, tagBase, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        }
    }
}
```

Now in your view you have to import `MyNamespace` to use this extension method.
You can import a namespace in Razor by specifying it like this on the top of the page.

```
@using MyNamespace
```

Comment: i've done this.. and i have access to the methods/extensions. It's just that in my view when i try to use it, it asks me for the first parameter but it shouldn't. It's asking me to pass an instance of itself i think?

Comment: @billy can you post the view?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a post that covers creating extension methods for the HtmlHelper.DropDownList helper. Check it out...it might be of help. I cover the `DropDownList` and `DropDownListFor` methods and go over including the reference to the namespace for your extension method class in both the Razor view file and the `web.config`.

[Populate html select lists from data in a view model in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application](http://www.iwantmymvc.com/populate-drop-down-list-mvc-3)